# Which core modules use RabbitMQ in Magento Open Source 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, message-queue, rabbit-mq

Starting with Magento 2.3.0, the Magento_Queue module for RabbitMQ becomes part of the Open Source edition.

Source:

- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Magento-2-Open-Source-has-a-new-Queueing-System/ba-p/92300
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html

But I cannot find documentation on how it's being used in the core. Are there already features in the Open Source version, formerly known as Community Edition, that use RabbitMQ, if configured? Which ones?

Comment: Did you get answer?

Comment: Is it mandatory to install rabbit mq if we are using magneto 2.3.2 or else without rabbit mq also will magento works with all scenarios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find queue consumers by searching for `etc/queue_consumer.xml` files.

In Magento 2.3.0 Open Source, there was one, `async.operations.all`, from the Magento_WebapiAsync module, the asynchronous API.

In Magento 2.3.2 Open Source, the following have been added:

- `product_action_attribute.update` from Magento_Catalog
- `product_action_attribute.website.update` from Magento_Catalog
- `codegeneratorProcessor` from Magento_SalesRule
- `exportProcessor` from Magento_ImportExport

But they all specify `connection=db`, not `connection=amqp`, which means they use MySQL as queue backend by default.

Comment: did you find out how to force all other queue consumers to use amqp? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @jaredchu I did not try it but you should be able to override it in a custom module like any other xml configuration. Make the module depend on the respective core modules, create etc/queue_consumer.xml and the same nodes with connection=amqp