# Magento 2.3 CE: Remove/Disable RabbitMQ feature completely

Tags: magento2.3.3, rabbit-mq, message-queue

Does anyone know any way to disable/remove [RabbitMQ](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html) from Magento 2.3.3 as this involves queues like `product_action_attribute.update` , `product_action_attribute.website.update` and `exportProcessor`?

While doing product bulk attribute update/product import, the queue table is populating even if RabbitMQ is not installed.

Due to this catalog is not updating.
Console commands like **queue:consumers** keeps running.

Saw this also - [Which core modules use RabbitMQ in Magento Open Source 2.3?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243804/which-core-modules-use-rabbitmq-in-magento-open-source-2-3)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to disable it as it's a core system you might not be able to. As ever with Magento it's wrapped up in lots of xml files. You can use the cron to run them instead, it'll run as per your cron settings. You just have to add the below into the env.php (as long as a badly coded console module isn't setting the app state in a constructor, which disabled all kinds of things.)

`'cron_consumers_runner' => array( 'cron_run' => true, 'max_messages' => 10000, 'consumers' => array( 'consumer1', 'consumer2', ) ),`

Consumers can be an empty array which will fire all of them each time the job fires. There are also some settings in the admin console in store > configuration > system I believe.